# Arm64e Architecture for iOS 12.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build-settings

I am trying to run my app on my phone with iOS 12.0.
Xcode is giving me this error, 
*"Phone doesn’t support any of Project.App’s architectures. You can add Phone’s arm64e architecture to Project’s Architectures build setting"*

I have added the arm64e to the build settings, still the error remains.

Comment: try clearing derived data

Comment: I have tried that.

Comment: Ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours on it.
I have been to able to solve it just by updating the Xcode 9.3 to Xcode 10

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disable "Build Active Architecture Only" ?.

XS Max use arm64e as native arch which Xcode 10 doesn't supported.